# Initializing a const char **

Tags: c++, user-interface, pointers, c-strings

Edit: Removed some unhelpful code

I am using IMGUI for my game's GUI library, and I am trying to implement listboxes. However my const char ** does not seem be read correctly by IMGUI.

```
#include <tinydir.h>
#include <tinyxml2.h>
#include <cpplocate/ModuleInfo.h>
#include <cpplocate/cpplocate.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <easylogging++.h>

#include "DmuxCommon.hpp"
#include "Garage.hpp"
#include "client/Game.hpp"

irr::f32 garageRotationRate = irr::f32(1.0f);
irr::f32 gChassisRotation;
irr::f32 gCameraRotation;
int selection = 0;

namespace menu {

const char **Garage::names;


  Garage::Garage() :
    Gui(),
    pMainScreen(Game::device->getSceneManager()->addEmptySceneNode()),
    pMoonScreen(Game::device->getSceneManager()->addEmptySceneNode()),
    availableChassis(getAvailableChassises()) {

    // Prepare double rendering
    pRenderTarget = Game::device->getVideoDriver()->addRenderTargetTexture(irr::core::dimension2d<irr::u32>(384, 300), "Moon");

    pRenderTextureID = pGUI->createTexture(pRenderTarget);

    names = new const char *[availableChassis.size()];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < availableChassis.size(); ++i) {
      names[i] = availableChassis[i].c_str();
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < availableChassis.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << names[i] << std::endl; // This shows the content of the const char ** correctly
    }
  }

  void Garage::show() {

    //Rendering the node
    Game::device->getVideoDriver()->setRenderTarget(pRenderTarget, true, true, irr::video::SColor(255, 120.0f, 120.0f, 120.0f));
    pMoonScreen->setVisible(true);
    pMainScreen->setVisible(false);
    Game::device->getSceneManager()->setActiveCamera(pMoonCam);
    Game::device->getSceneManager()->drawAll();
    Game::device->getVideoDriver()->setRenderTarget(0, true, true, irr::video::SColor(255, 100, 101, 140));

    pMoonScreen->setVisible(false);
    pMainScreen->setVisible(true);
    Game::device->getSceneManager()->setActiveCamera(pMainCam);

    pGUI->updateTexture(pRenderTextureID, pRenderTarget);

    if(gChassis == nullptr) {
      gChassis = Game::device->getSceneManager()->addMeshSceneNode(Game::device->getSceneManager()->getMesh((std::string(cpplocate::findModule("dmux").value("chassisDir") + "el-camino/el-camino.obj")).c_str()));
      gChassis->setParent(pMoonScreen);
      gChassis->setPosition(irr::core::vector3df(0, 0, 0));
      gChassis->setMaterialFlag(irr::video::EMF_LIGHTING, false);
      gChassis->setMaterialFlag(irr::video::EMF_BACK_FACE_CULLING, false);

      pMainCam = Game::device->getSceneManager()->addCameraSceneNode(pMoonScreen, irr::core::vector3df(0, 0, 0), irr::core::vector3df(0, 0, 0));
      pMoonCam = Game::device->getSceneManager()->addCameraSceneNode(pMoonScreen, irr::core::vector3df(0, 0, -5), irr::core::vector3df(0, 0, 0));
      pMoonCam->setTarget(gChassis->getPosition());
      gCameraRotation = irr::f32(1.0f);
    }

    ImGui::SetNextWindowPos(ImVec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
    ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(ImVec2(Game::playerSettings.currentWindowSize.first,
                                    Game::playerSettings.currentWindowSize.second - (Game::playerSettings.currentWindowSize.second / 9)));

    ImGui::Begin("Customize a combat vehicle");

    ImGui::PushItemWidth(120);
    ImGui::ListBox("", &selection, names, ((int)(sizeof(names)/sizeof(*names))));
    ImGui::PopItemWidth();

    ImGui::End();
  }
}
```

Compiling this file with the rest of my project I get a window that looks like this

https://s4.postimg.org/cyrdl2p8d/DMUX_130.png

As you can see it does not print out the entire contents of the const char ** as it should. But the cout statements are correctly printing out the contents of the array which should be

- "El Camino"
- "Moscovitch"
- "ElCamino"

Without quotes, it is getting the first value correctly as pictured. Is there anything wrong I am doing involving the initialization of the names variable?
The sizeof is strange because of the code in IMGUI's imgui_demo.cpp it used this macro for sizeof on listboxes

```
#define IM_ARRAYSIZE(_ARR) ((int)(sizeof(_ARR)/sizeof(*_ARR)))
```

So I just took the raw input rather than using the define.

Comment: Hint: what is `sizeof(names)`?

Comment: Try creating an MCVE that illustrates your problem.  There is so much unrelated cruft in the code you have posted that you can hardly expect someone else to wade through to find your problem if you haven't bothered yourself.   In the process of cutting out irrelevant stuff, you might have an "aha!" moment and work out for yourself what the problem is.   If not, other people will have a fighting chance of helping you.

Comment: If I were to provide a "minimal" example; then that would just involve me cout'ing the contents of said const char **, which I already mentioned works correctly, the issue is within the GUI code so I included that in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: putting in better answer

I got it after all day of looking at it! I fixed it by saying

```
availableChassis.size()
```

I managed to fix it, thank you @Ismail Badawi @Paul and @1201ProgramAlarm for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing what you're telling it:  Displaying 1 choice in the list box.  Your calculation of the number of list elements is wrong.  `sizeof(names)` is the same as `sizeof(*names)`, since both are pointers.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I should change it to? I tried availableChassis.size() and it still does the same thing.

Comment: @bkeys You are allocating `availableChassis.size()` elements for your `names`, so just pass `availableChassis.size()` where you need to pass the size of `names`. `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` works for arrays on stack, when `sizeof(array)` will result in actual size of the `array`. In your case `sizeof(names)==sizeof(char**)` which is not what you need.

Comment: @Paul I try to pass sizeof(availableChassis.size()) into the call to the ListBox function, however it seg faults when I attempt that

Comment: @bkeys `sizeof(availableChassis.size())==sizeof(size_t)` which is either 4 or 8 depending on your platform. You need just `availableChassis.size()` without `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

Also if your data is not in that const char* [] format, then instead of creating a temporary array you could pass a lambda to ListBox to access your strings directly from your availableChassis[] names.